# How to add Leflet plugin to R script

Tags: r, leaflet

I have troubles adding a Leaflet plugin to my R code. Specifically, I am trying to add the [Leaflet.zoomhome](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#heatmaps) plugin (See upper-left corner in [this demo](http://torfsen.github.io/leaflet.zoomhome/).)

I have unsuccessfully tried to follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92#file-leaflet-heat-r-L16) and this is what I have so far, which is not working.

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

map <- 
  leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
  leaflet::addTiles(group = "OSM")

zoom_home_plugin <- htmlDependency(
  name = "leaflet.zoomhome", 
  version = "99.99.99",
  src = c(href = "https://github.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome/tree/master/dist/"),
  script = "leaflet.zoomhome.js")

RegisterPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))

  return(map)
}

map <- RegisterPlugin(map, zoom_home_plugin) %>%
  onRender("function(el, x) {
    zoomHome.addTo(this);
  }")

map
```

Any ideas on what is causing the error and how to rewrite the code to implement the plugin?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something with this code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

map <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  onRender(
    "
function(el,x) {
  var zoomHome = L.Control.zoomHome();
  zoomHome.addTo(this);
}
")

temp_folder <- tempdir()
download.file(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome/master/dist/leaflet.zoomhome.js",
  file.path(temp_folder, 'leaflet.zoomhome.js')
)
download.file(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome/master/dist/leaflet.zoomhome.css",
  file.path(temp_folder, 'leaflet.zoomhome.css')
)

tagList(
  tags$head(
    includeScript(file.path(temp_folder, 'leaflet.zoomhome.js')),
    includeCSS(file.path(temp_folder, 'leaflet.zoomhome.css')),
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"),
  ),
  map
) %>%
  browsable()
```

As i understand, your code is trying to access *"https://github.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome/tree/master/dist/"* but the correct way would be to point to *"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome/master/dist/leaflet.zoomhome.js"*. Even with this, it seems that putting a `<script>` tag in the header does not work with raw github links, as the js and stylesheet are not loaded (at least in all my tries). So as a workaround I downloaded the script and the stylesheet directly to a temp folder and use that files in the html header.

Also I added the fontawesome dependency and modified the `onRender` script to match the example in [leaflet.zoomhome README](https://github.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome)